# How to restore a mysql database dump in a Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have an sql file which contains all of the data I'd like to store in a mysql database inside of a docker container. I have tried pulling a mysql image form dockerhub, but I couldn't figure out how to access the dump on my local machine from the docker container. Furthermore, I tried port mapping a local port to the docker machine and restoring the database through table plus on those ports, but it simply restored the data base on that port on my local machine.

I am looking for a high level overview, or a tutorial / documentation to reference for this process.

Ideally, I would start from scratch and

1. Create a new container or image
2. install mysql
3. restore my db from the dump file inside the docker container

Any help would be appreciated I've been stuck on this all day. Thank you.

If you need me to provide any more details please let me know ^__^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run that command, replacing the right parameters.

`cat <file.sql> | docker exec -i <container> /usr/bin/mysql -u <username> --password=<ps> <db>`

Comment: ran this line of code, is it normal for it to take a long time? the sql file is about 6gbs

Comment: Yes it will take some time if the export is big